# Azrue Function TIME out issue always timing out at 3.8 min +-

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

We have created an Azure function in C# to process some .csv files and save each record to a database.
The problem is that the DB is a third party and we have no control over the SP's being used and saving a
record can take 4-5 seconds each. So if I have a .csv with 100 records the time exceeds the default time out of the Logic app (single tenant nonconsumption) I have modified my host_json to have the following. and did the run-test and
it takes about 4-5 min with 100 records.[image]

"functionTimeout": "00:30:00",

but it still times out with an error Http request failed: the server did not respond within the timeout limit. Please see logic app limits at https://aka.ms/logic-apps-limits-and-config#http-limits.
It times out at 3.9 min (Logic App time out)

Is there any why to increase the Logic app time out?

Answer (score 0):

For longer running operations, use an asynchronous polling pattern or an "Until" loop.

To work around timeout limits when you call function that has a callable endpoint, you can use the built-in Azure Logic Apps action instead, which you can find in the designer's operation picker under Built-in.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could you point me to an asynchronous polling pattern, not finding much in Google (maybe my phrasing)

Comment: @LJHHouston After passing data to function it should return 202 Accepted without waiting for function app to complete it's process.

This will works in case if output coming from function App is not used in further steps in logic app.
For More details : [Async-Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-api-app#async-pattern)